# How to tell pure javascript to to constantly check a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have an conditional command,

```js
    if("some condition"){
        //something to do
    }
```

So now, I want this condition to constantly repeat itself without blocking the program.

I'm not using jQuery.
I'm cannot acces new files

Comment: Use `setInterval()`, perhaps? Seems like the best thing to suggest given the limited information provided.

Comment: Yes I noticed..ty

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Polling with `setInterval` is less than ideal. If you want this to be a performant solution, you could try to figure out what set of circumstances lead to the condition changing and fire a function whenever that happens. Conditions don't just change by themselves, you should be able figure out the cause and hook into it.

Comment: "constantly repeat" is not really a logical concept in computing. you need to be more specific in what you want. "checking once every mili-second" is more logical than what you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function () { 
  if("some condition"){
    //something to do
  }
}, 10);
```

done.

technically it's not "constantly", but it will check once every 1/100th of a second.

Comment: Won't `setInterval` cause potential memory leaks if it holds on to variables declared outside the scope?

Comment: hard to tell based on the limited code provided. but it does accomplish what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

> Without blocking the program

You can take a look at [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Supported in all modern browsers barring IE11.

Sample code,

```
var w;

function startWorker() {
  if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
    w = new Worker("workers.js");
    w.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log(event.data);
    };
  } else {
    console.log("Not supported");
  }
}

function stopWorker() { 
  w.terminate();
  w = undefined;
}
```

And your `worker.js` code would be something like,

```
function checkCondition() {
  while (true) { // since you want the condition to be checked "continuously"
    if ("some condition") {
     postMessage() // whatever you pass here would be collected in `onmessage` in the above snippet
    }
  }
}

checkCondition();
```